# add-symbol-file returns -s invalid argument when trying to add module's object file

Tags: c, linux-kernel, gdb, kernel-module

I'm debugging `vmlinux` with `gdb vmlinux /proc/kcore`, and I want to add a symbol file, I installed a module and then check the location of `.bss`, `.data` and `.init` in `/sys/module/simple_module/sections`. When I try to use the `add-symbol-file` with the object file of my module and also the section's locations, `gdb` returns `Unrecognized argument " -s"`. But from `help add-symbol-file`, I can see that `-s` actually a valid argument.

```
add-symbol-file simple_module.ko 0xc0ce9000 \ -s .bss 0xc0d833c0 \ -s .data 0xc0d83000
```

I don't think that the code of my module really necessary, but whatever

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("whoami");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple LKM");

int i; // non-init variable
char text[20] = "Hello, World!";

static int __init initialization_function(void)
{
    pr_info("Module: my message!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_funcion(void)
{    
    pr_info("Module: Cleanup done, exiting.\n");
}

module_init(initialization_function);
module_exit(cleanup_funcion);
```

Comment: Remove the `\ ` from `\ -s`. The backslash is quoting the following space, so the space is not acting as an argument separator.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Oh that's right. I saw that command in *LDD3*

Comment: They probably had the backslash as the last character in a line. In that case, it means that the current line and the next line should be joined together.